# xtk 2D renderer linking with onMousedown position

Tags: xtk

Is there a way to link three 2D renderers together so that when one is clicked on the other two move to the slices of the point that was clicked? [Here is an example of what I mean](http://ric.uthscsa.edu/mango/MangoKiosk.html).

The current onMousedown behavior in a 2drenderer is to adjust window level, can this behavior be turned off, on or modified?

Comment: I have quite a similar issue, and I think I will try the following approach : use 3x 3D renderers, 1 with a perspective camera3D, the 2 others with an orthographic camera3D (i've to code it), then prevent the orthographics from rotationEvent (in the camera or in the interactor), then create a onDblClick_ event so that the visible slices change in the volume, and it should be seen in the 3 renderers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible right now. There was some work on unprojecting a 3D scene to get from screen coordinates to world coordinates. See https://github.com/xtk/X/issues/78 Unfortunately it hasn't made it into head yet.

This would be the first step, then we would have to transfer the 3D coordinate to volume space.

And for 2D this is even a different story. So sadly, not possible right now but would be a great feature and any contribution is welcome :D