# How do I get the volume coordinates from a tri-planar set of 2D images in XTK?

Tags: xtk

I have an application where I would like to get the volume coordinates from a tri-planar set of 2D images (axial, sagital, coronal), similar to what is displayed in the bottom panel of [Lesson 13](http://lessons.goxtk.com/13/). I do not need the 3D view currently, so this feels like a simplified version of [finding-world-coordinates-from-screen-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530198/finding-world-coordinates-from-screen-coordinates).

Getting the volume coordinates onMouseDown also seems like a required step in the recent question [xtk-2d-renderer-linking-with-onmousedown-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231442/xtk-2d-renderer-linking-with-onmousedown-position).

Any help or advise on how to get the volume coordinates is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255899/1183453. In short: this is not possible right now but certainly should be. I think that it might be even easier in the 2D case. We need functionality to map a screen position to volume space. We should create a GitHub issue and discuss.